# ID, count where Y by ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to produce the below column ID_Error_Flag_Y_Count. Please see below data have and data want. Please see my attempt below.

**I want to count how many times Error_Flag = Y by ID.**

My Attempt: Create a pivot table by ID and where Error Flag = Y. Then VLOOKUP by ID and add the ID_Error_Flag_Y_Count to the original file. THis method works but I want to know if there is an easier way.

```
Data Have   
ID  Error Flag
1   Y
2   Y
3   N
3   Y
3   Y
```

This is what I want

```
Data Want       
ID  Error Flag  ID_Error_Flag_Y_Count
1   Y   1
2   Y   1
3   N   2
3   Y   2
3   Y   2
```

Comment: Use COUNTIFS here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS:

```
 =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$6,A2,$B$2:$B$6,"Y")
```

[image]